# Having GROUP BY multiple values giving me all possible combinations

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join, cross-join

Imagine the following table:

```
type cond
A    good
A    good
A    bad
B    good
B    bad
C    good
C    bad
D    good
D    bad
E    worse
```

If I count and group by both `type` and `cond` I’ll get this:

```
count type cond
2     A    good
1     A    bad
1     B    good
1     B    bad
1     C    good
1     C    bad
1     D    good
1     D    bad
1     E    worse
```

But for better summarizing the data into a table I’d rather like a result like this:

```
count type cond
2     A    good
1     A    bad
0     A    worse
1     B    good
1     B    bad
0     B    worse
1     C    good
1     C    bad
0     C    worse
1     D    good
1     D    bad
0     D    worse
0     E    good
0     E    bad
1     E    worse
```

I already managed to cross join all existing `type`s with all existing `cond`s but then I can’t count anymore.
I also tried to left join the result against all existing `type`s or `cond`s but that didn’t work either.

The SUM-CASE-WHEN strategy doesn’t work here as I want to have it dynamic, i.e. I don’t know how many `type`s or `cond`s there will be.

Is there a simple (or even a complicated) solution to generate a linear matrix of the grouped data? (Bonus: …or even transpose it, i.e. 2D matrix, to have one group as table headers?)

Comment: Have you a parent table with values "good", "bad", "worse"?

Comment: @JoeTaras: I don’t have a table with all possible conditions but it can be dynamically synthesized (and nested if neccessary) with `SELECT cond FROM table GROUP BY cond`

Comment: Ook, about normalization, is better you have a table with those values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(c.type) as `count`, a.type, b.cond
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT type
    FROM table_name
  ) a
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT cond
    FROM table_name
  ) b
  LEFT JOIN
    table_name c ON c.type = a.type AND c.cond = b.cond
GROUP BY a.type, b.cond
ORDER BY a.type, b.cond
```

Test it: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d35e7f/6)

**EDIT:**

To show results in 2D matrix with one group as table headers, you must known group names before running query. Query can be:

```
SELECT 
  a.type,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN b.cond = 'good'  THEN c.type ELSE NULL END) as good,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN b.cond = 'bad'   THEN c.type ELSE NULL END) as bad,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN b.cond = 'worse' THEN c.type ELSE NULL END) as worse
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT type
    FROM table_name
  ) a
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT cond
    FROM table_name
  ) b
  LEFT JOIN
    table_name c ON c.type = a.type AND c.cond = b.cond
GROUP BY a.type
ORDER BY a.type
```

Test it: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d35e7f/5)

Answer (score 0):

For better data structure you must have a table with `cond` anagraph but...

You can build your cartesian product with two subqueries, one for all types and one for all conds, so, you have a subquery on `SELECT` fields where you can count the elements of these couples.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE app(type char, cond varchar(10));

INSERT INTO app values
('A', 'good'),
('A', 'good'),
('A', 'bad'),
('B', 'good'),
('B', 'bad'),
('C', 'good'),
('C', 'bad'),
('D', 'good'),
('D', 'bad'),
('E', 'worse')

select t1.cond, t2.type, (select count(*) from app a3 where a3.cond = t1.cond 
and (a3.type = t2.type)) as total
from 
    (select distinct cond
    from app a1) as t1
cross join
    (select distinct type
    from app a2) as t2
order by t2.type, t1.cond
```

[Show SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e82d/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    A.type,
    A.cond,
    case
        when B.cnt is null then 0
        else B.cnt
    end
from
    (select 
        type, cond
    from
        (SELECT distinct
        cond
    from
        package)
    cross join (select distinct
        type
    from
        package)) A
        left join
    (select 
        type, cond, count(*) as cnt
    from
        package
    group by type , cond) B ON A.cond = B.cond and A.type = B.type
order by type
```

Comment: can someone please indent it Am not able to